# Laravel Session Timeout on Login

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-passport

I have an SPA app that uses Laravel Passport.  For the web, I am using sessions.  If I set my `session.lifetime` to 5 minutes, sit on the login page for 5 minutes, and then login, I receive a 419 (session timeout) from the server.  What is the proper way to handle this.  A non-authenticated sessions starts when the user loads the page.  When the user logs in, they are still using that same session.  I can detect a 419 on login and try again, but it doesn't seem optimal.  I imagine other people have run into this.  I think Sanctum makes a xsrf token request before login so that the landing page doesn't need a session.  Should I make a fetch before logging to create a new session and refresh XSRF?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"sit on the login page for 5 minutes"_ Don't... do... that? Is this even a concern? Do you know that your users are actually having this issue? Don't try to solve problems you don't have by adding code you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, it has been reported by various customers which we can confirm via logs.